# Query allowed values of an attribute in Rally using javascript

Tags: rally

Could someone tell me how to query allowed values of an attribute in Rally using javascript?
Particularly, I want to query all possible states of a Defect

I know that it can be done with REST api

```
DynamicJsonObject allowedValues = restApi.GetAllowedAttributeValues("defect", "state");
```

Is there a javascript equivalence?

Answer (score 1):

You can use RallyDataSource from the App SDK (note, this is the original one, not the new ExtJS-based SDK currently in preview).  See the Attribute Values example on this page:

http://developer.rallydev.com/help/data-examples

Answer (score 0):

You may wish to try something along the lines of:

```
    queryConfig = {
        type: 'Defect', 
        key : 'defectStates', 
        attribute: 'State'
    };
```